# Symfony form required only on custom validator fields

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am struggling to find a way to make `required` only those fields, who have my own custom validator attached. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @AdminAssert\CustomNotBlank(          // <--- this is my custom validator
 *     groups={
 *         //...
 *     }
 * )
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Email(
 *     groups={
 *         //...
 *     }
 * )
 */
private $email;
```

So in the example above only `$name` must have `'required' => true`, because it was Validated by my own validator `CustomNotBlank`. And no field which does not have this validator no matter what other validation settings they have.

The `FormType` does not really matter because I have many fields of many Form Types (this is just a simple example of two text type fields)

Comment: and you don't want to put it on the form ?

Comment: add the formtype to your post

Comment: no, they all ought to be displayed in the form. But only those with my validator should be 'required'.

Comment: Why can't you just manually set this?

Comment: I am seeking a more convenient solution for a reusable automated bundle than to set things manually.

Answer (score 2):

By default `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorTypeGuesser` should do this job if the property has one of these constraints:

```
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull'
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank'
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue'
```

So you might need a new TypeGuesser to add your custom constraint to the list. A simple solution could be **decorate the `form.type_guesser.validator` service** and override the public method `guessRequiredForConstraint()` which contains this list:

```
public function guessRequiredForConstraint(Constraint $constraint)
{
    switch (get_class($constraint)) {
        case 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull':
        case 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank':
        case 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue':
        case 'AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\CustomNotBlank': // <-- adds here
            return new ValueGuess(true, Guess::HIGH_CONFIDENCE);
    }
}
```

and the `required` attribute should be there in the form field if it has the custom constraint.

**Plus: [How to decorate the service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)**

Creates a new class `AppBundle\Validator\ValidatorTypeGuesser` that extends from the original type guesser, next adds the overridden method and register it with the same service id of the original, including its tag and required arguments:

```
services:
    form.type_guesser.validator:
        class: AppBundle\Validator\ValidatorTypeGuesser
        arguments: ['@validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory']
        tags: ['form.type_guesser']
```

Comment: Wow! Looks exactly like what I was looking for! I can't check it right now, but I will notify tomorrow when I am able to. Thanks very much.

Comment: Might I ask you why haven't you added `decorate: ...` option to the service? The doc you provided says it is kinda necessary.

Comment: You're wolcome! Well, because you need remove the old service and `decorates` option avoids this.

Comment: ycerto, surprisingly I only managed to do it with simple TextType fields. All other fields (of connected one-to-many, many-to-one entities, datatype fields etc) are not checked by this validator and still remained `required`. Is there anything I miss?

Comment: So, I report: this only works if you do not specify the type of the field. Once you specify it (even if it is TextType) this validator does not check it

Comment: Yep, this is the default behavior, the type guesser wakes up when you're omitted the form type. Btw, if you have to set the form type, why not set the `required` option manually?